# Unique Array Values across Two Functions and Two Divs

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I want to obtain different height values for each div in both the 'CardContainer' and 'Two' divs. I would like to randomize those values upon each click event without repeating any of the values in the array.

http://codepen.io/jlhanna/pen/oBjrov

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <button id="press" type="Button" value="Shake">Test</button>
  <div id="cardContainer"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#cardContainer div {border:solid 1px black; width: 20px;}
#two {border:solid 1px black; width: 20px; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 50px;}
button {display: block;}
```

**JS**

```
var balls90 = ['1px', '5px', '10px', '20px', '40px', '80px', '160px', '320px'];
var cardContainer= document.getElementById("cardContainer");
var two= document.getElementById("two");
var $all = $("#cardContainer").push(balls90);
var $next = $("#two").push(balls90);

function getNumbers() {
var player1 = new Array(); 
balls90.sort(function() {
  return [Math.floor(Math.random() * balls90.length)];
});

$("#press").click(function() {
$("#cardContainer").empty();  
});  

document.getElementById("press").addEventListener('click',getNumbers,true);
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.height = (balls90[i]);
    cardContainer.appendChild(div);       
}
} 

getNumbers();

function getMore() {
var player1 = new Array(); 
balls90.sort(function() {
  return [Math.floor(Math.random() * balls90.length)];
});      

$("#press").click(function() {
$("#two").empty();  
});  

document.getElementById("press").addEventListener('click',getMore,true);
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.height = (balls90[i]);
   div.style.border = "thin solid black";
    two.appendChild(div);       
}
} 

getMore();
```

Comment: can you tell us what is the problem you're running into?

Comment: If I click the button, I get similar values across both the 'cardContainer' and 'Two 'divs. I want both divs to pull from the same array with just unique values.

Comment: Your code is pretty confusing. `getNumbers` and `getMore` seem like largely the same thing.

Comment: they are the same function but I couldn't get the same function to work for two different divs so I made two separate functions

Answer (score 0):

would this work?

```
var balls90 = ['1px', '5px', '10px', '20px', '40px', '80px', '160px', '320px'];
var randomBalls90 = [];
var $cardContainer = $("#cardContainer");
var $two = $("#two");

$("#press").click(function() {
  $("#cardContainer, #two").empty();
  getNumbers();
});  

function makedivs (el) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    var $div = $("<div>");

    $div.css({
      height: randomBalls90[0],
      border: "1px solid red"
    });

    $(el).append($div);
    randomBalls90.splice(0, 1);
  }
}

function getNumbers() {
  balls90.sort(function() {
    return [Math.floor(Math.random() * balls90.length)];
  });

  randomBalls90 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(balls90));

  makedivs($cardContainer);
  makedivs($two);
}

getNumbers();
```

Basically, I made making the random divs as a seperate function that accepts a element to append to.

When getNumbers is run, it clones the balls90 Array `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` then loops through the array and on each loop, you remove the first object of the array so it's never repeated.